# Swift location comes back nil

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

This code was functioning earlier, and now it keeps crashing because the location is coming back as nil.  I'm not sure where this error is coming from or how to fix it.  From what I can tell,  my code is correct.  Any help?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class LocationController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!

    var manager:CLLocationManager!
    var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.Map.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
            self.Map.showsUserLocation = true

            //self.Map.removeAnnotations(self.theMap.annotations)

            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


            let location = self.locationManager.location

            var latitude: Double = location.coordinate.latitude
            var longitude: Double = location.coordinate.longitude

            println("current latitude :: \(latitude)")
            println("current longitude :: \(longitude)")
        }
```

Comment: Would you want to tell us what line the crash is on?

Comment: From the docs: "The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been retrieved." You have to handle a nil returned value.

Comment: If you try to access your locationManager's location using this line:  `let location = self.locationManager.location` right after starting your location manager's updates with this line: `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` it's going to be nil since your location manager will undoubtedly not have had enough time to have received a location. Wait until `didUpdateLocations` is called to know for sure a location has been found.

Comment: It crashes on let location = self.location!anager.location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` property of `CLLocationManager` is declared as:

```
@NSCopying var location: CLLocation! { get }
```

and thus your `let location` could be filled with a `nil` value.  Perhaps this declaration changed recently as Apple scrubs their interfaces related to optionals.

You'll need to bind your `latitude` and `longitude` while respecting a possible `nil`.